# SQL Server in memory cache

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching, in-memory

I want to implement a simple in memory cache for an sql server 2008 R2 Express Edition.

Requirements:

1. The cache must be visible for all users
2. The cache is synchronized with a persistent table. Over this persistent table might occur heavy CRUD operations.

My solution:
Create a bucket of CLR procedures that stands into a .NET assembly. These procedures will be named:

- Add (param1, ... paramN);
- Remove (param1 ... paramN);
- GetAll ();

where param1... paramN is my persistent table data specific that i want to cache.

Behind the scenes I will organize in memory data maybe into a HashSet for O (1) add / remove. Then, I will create a trigger for Insert / Delete operations (only inserts and deletes can occur on the persistent table) that would call these methods (Add / Remove). The big issue is that the transaction can be rolled back. How can I find out that the transaction with a specific ID was rolled back? There is a server level event that I can listen?

Please give me whatever alternatives you know. I know that SQL Server 2014 supports memory optimized OLTP tables but ... this feature is active only for SQL Server enterprise edition :D.

Another alternative would be to create a temporary table with ## (visible on all connections) BUT:

1. The table will be stored in TEMPDB. If the tempDB is stored in RAM, there might be a performance boost but then it comes the second issue:
2. Searching in it (for a specific item) in this temporary table will cost me O ( Log ( N )) because behind the scenes if I create an index, there will be a B-tree. My In memory alternative will ensure that lookups will cost O (1).

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve with this cache? Sounds complicated, and can you be sure it even fixes your problem?

Comment: @JamesZ The ideea is that I want to perform O (1) lookups but sql server is able to do only O ( Log N) wich is unnaccepable for my system when I am dealing with very big number of records. Secondly, There's a huge performance benefit if I grab my data from memory instead of reading it from disk / persistent table. Anyway, my requirement is quite complicated but the ideea is simple: instead of a join I would call finally a CLR function that gets my data in O (1) time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have enough RAM, you're really not reading the data from disc, all your often accessed data will be in memory. I don't really know the limits of express edition in detail, so those could be causing issues you're facing. I think you should at least consider upgrading to standard version, especially if you very big number of records, since you'll most likely run out of space too.

Temp DB is no exception, it will be either in disc or RAM, depending on how much memory you have and what is being accessed the most. Just creating cache 1:1 for data from other tables into tempdb is not useful, you'll just waste your memory for storing the same data twice.

The in memory OLTP of SQL Server 2012 wouldn't probably help you at all. The point of it is not that you have the data in memory, but to reduce the overhead of locking & latching etc.

Comment: You miss my point:I WANT SEARCH TIME TO BE IN O (1) TIME !!!!. SQL Server does not provide for me such a performance. Or does it ? (maybe I can declare an index to behave like a hashtable but I didn't saw this option to exist)

Comment: Why use SQL server at all?  It sounds like you're biased towards memory based technology so why not Gemfire or VoltDB to start with rather than building something around a technology you're just going to bypass?

Comment: Your question doesn't say anywhere that O(1) is a requirement. If you really plan to run selects through CLR, I don't think you get even close to that. If you need that, then you probably should start looking into different platform than SQL Server, like @BradD said already.

Comment: My database is 99.99999 % user by selecting from tables using classical sql. This is a very specific problem that has to do with sort of dynamic columns

Comment: @JameZ please stop sugesting another db engine, i cannot migrate this legacy system into a completelly new paradigm/architecture

Comment: I think in memory OLTP only applies since SQL Server 2014.